# Data doesn't appears on javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a problem with javafx. It doesn't show any data from my DB I tried to enter some data manually but it doesn't work neither. I saw all the post around this issue but none of them bring me a fix.

Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for my English.

Main class :

```
 private ObservableList<Index> LstClient = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
 public MainClass {
   LstClient.add(new Index("Lesinge"));
 }
 public ObservableList<Index> getLstClient(){return LstClient;}
```

Here my controller :

```
@FXML
private TableView<Index> personneTable;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Index, String> NomColonne;

private Mainclass main;


public PersonneMapping() { } 

public void setMainApp(Mainclass mainApp) {

    this.main = mainApp;

    personneTable.setItems(main.getLstClient());

     @FXML
     public void Initialize () {

      NomColonne.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNom())


   }
```

Here my Index

```
private StringProperty Nom = new SimpleStringProperty();
public Index( String Nom ) {

    this.Nom.set(Nom);

}
public StringProperty getNom() {
    return Nom;
}
public void setNom(StringProperty Nom) {
    this.Nom = Nom;
}


}
```

My fxml files is good it has the good controller and fx id on each columns

Comment: a) Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.
b) Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: `initialize` starts with a lowercase letter. Also your first code snippet results in compilation errors: `public MainClass { ... }` could be a constructor, but then it's missing the `()`; it could be a class declaration, but then it's missing the `class` keyword or it could be a initializer block, but then the `public MainClass` part is wrong...

Comment: Ok i am new on SO sorry i made a mistake for the "minimal reproducible example". But,also thank you my issue only come from my initialize with the lowercase. thanks a lot.